# grid column filter based on existing values

Tags: magento2, order-grid, custom-column-grid

In Magento 2.1.8 I trying to add a custom column to the admin order grid, that contains the cc_type field.

Long story short, I managed to make the column appear, display the correct data, and be updated dynamically via di.xml.

What I could not achieve yet is the filter in the grid. I need the filter to display an option list based on existing values in cc_type.

Cc_type is a field that is populated by payment methods, so it is not possible to provide a list of all the possible values. I want the filter to provide only the options that actually are stored in the table.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="cc_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CcType\CcType</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Payment Details</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CcType/CcType.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CcType;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class Options
 */
class CcType implements OptionSourceInterface
{

    public function toOptionArray() {
        $optionList = [];
        //retrive options with some kind of collection?
        return $optionList;
    }

}
```

Anyone has any hints on how to retrieve the existing values and populate the filter options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the data collection being used by the sales order grid, extract the field data, and create an option for each unique result:

```
class CcTypes implements OptionSourceInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection
     */
    protected $salesCollection;

    protected $options;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->salesCollection = $collectionFactory->getReport("sales_order_grid_data_source");
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if ($this->options === null) {

            foreach ($this->salesCollection->addOrder('cc_type')->addFieldToSelect('cc_type')->distinct(true) as $order) {
                $ccType = $order->getCcType();
                $this->options[] = [
                    'value' => $ccType,
                    'label' => $ccType
                ];
            }
        }

        return $this->options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I slightly optimized the query: `$this->salesCollection->setOrder('cc_type', 'ASC')->addFieldToSelect('cc_type')->distinct(true)` and then skipped the `($lastItem !== $ccType)` check altogether.

Comment: Have you got any hints on how to cache the results? I noticed that the collection is loaded twice when loading the grid, and the `($this->options === null)` check is irrelevant, unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: The core registry could be used to store the collection using some plugin so it can be reused. Other than that I don't really know.